# Issue with WINE after NVIDIA Driver installation

Tags: linux, fedora, wine, nvidia-graphics-card

I used to be able to successfully play Pocket Tanks and Commandos on my Fedora 20 64bit system using WINE. Few days ago I finally got time to install NVIDIA Driver. After that, WINE is now not working. Whenever I start any application I get following error

```
[10:09] Abhinav@localhost Pocket Tanks Deluxe $ wine pockettanks.exe 
err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
err:winediag:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Direct rendering is disabled, most likely your 32-bit OpenGL drivers haven't been installed correctly (using GL renderer "GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M/integrated/SSE2", version "1.4 (2.1.2 NVIDIA 304.119)").
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f664,0x00000000), stub!
X Error of failed request:  GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  773
  Current serial number in output stream:  774
```

Without NVIDIA driver, The Gnome-Shell used to flicker while animating. So I would prefer to keep the driver installed. I dont understand why it is not working correctly after graphic driver installation? Propriety driver was suppose to perform better than  Nouveau driver, isn't it?

Comment: Have you checked what the message suggest ? Is the 32bit version of the proprietary driver also installed ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be able to resolve by deleting *.wine* dir in `/home`.

<sub>[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2100517&p=12491287#post12491287)</sub>

Comment: Still Not working,Now It Reconfigured the wine and recreated .wine folder. After that, Error Message is the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

only you needs winetricks and:

winetricks orm=backbuffer glsl=disable

On nvidia closed driver offcourse.

Comment: Could you explain this more clearly? To start with, what is winetricks?

Answer (score 0):

[Winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) seems to remedy the problem to execute the command:

```
winetricks orm=backbuffer glsl=disable
```

I don't know what exactly is meant by:

> On nvidia closed driver offcourse.

Comment: He means the proprietary NVIDIA graphics card driver. There is also an open-source driver, Nouveau.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the bug happens when wine try switching the resolution using XRandr extension.

so to resolve the issue you must disable or prevent wine from this behavior

go ahead and install **Q4Wine** from synaptic package manager and launch it

next go to **Programs** tab in the main window and right click on the prefix you are using by  and choose **Configure fake drive settings**

in the **Fake Drive Settings** window go to Video > X11 Driver and set UseRandR to N as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMHJJ.jpg

Comment: This question is almost 7-8 years old. In 2022, even nvidia has finally started providing their own drivers for linux.

These days, Bottles is much better than Q4Wine. It has support for proton too.